# Div y contenido Responsive

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, css3

**Requerimiento**

Crear un div responsive, es decir que cambie el tamaño del contenido pero la ubicación sea exactamente la misma, en mi caso, que cambie el tamaño del autobús y al mismo tiempo el de las cabezas, manteniendo la ubicación.

En este caso las cabezas cambian de tamaño pero el autobus no.

¿Es posible? , estoy utilizando bootstrap 3.

**(Al margen de la pregunta principal)**
Es posible agregar el DNI sobre cada cabeza y que sea Responsive?

**Código**

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
}
.bus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
.human1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 364px;
  width:4%;
}

.human2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 458px;
  width:4%;
}

.human3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 264px;
  width:4%;
}

.human4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 164px;
  width:4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <img class="bus" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX10405102.jpg" />
  <img class="human1" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
  
    <img class="human2" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
      <img class="human3" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
        <img class="human4" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
        
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: probaste con la clase `.cols` en los divs?

Comment: No me sirve, la posición tiene que ser absoluta, las cabezas tienen que estar justo en esa ubicación

Comment: Tu primer gran error es que tu estilo del autobús se aplica a la clase "bus", pero tu imagen de autobus tiene la clase "BUS". Cambia ésta última a minúsculas y tu bus cambiará de tamaño. El otro fallo, pero supongo que estás en ello, es que la posición de las cabezas está en píxeles y no en porcentaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola todo se puede jejeje, pero bootstrap no fue diseñado para ello, toca con css y su lógica de maquetación de toda la vida, pero vamos por pasos.

1. Todas las medidas tienen que estar en porcentajes para que todo sea funcional.
2. Te aconsejo que todas las cabezas, tengan una clase común, para no estar repitiendo el código en cada una.
3. El bus no es responsive, no porque los estilos que le pusistes esten mal, sino porque tu clase `BUS` esta en mayuscula y en el css, en minúscula `.bus`

Lo otro ya es opcional:

4. Recomiendo usar archivos .svg para que no se pixelen las imágenes.
5. Agrupa las imágenes (`img`) en etiquetas figure, es una buena práctica.

**Para lo del DNI es lo mismo que con las cabezas**, pero depende de tu diseño, mira como te lo propongo:

- Agrega un `span` con el contenido del DNI y con la misma clase `humanX` de la imagen que vas asociar y agregale otra clase en común como por ejemplo: `dni`.
- En el css, lo acomodas a la altura que necesites y con un tipo de letra y tamaño que necesites, para hacerlas responsive te recomiendo usar medidas `vmin` o `vmax`, `%`o `calc`.
- Usa `display:inline-block` en los `span`, para que pueda aceptar otros atributos que necesitas, por ejemplo `transform` o `width`.
- Como el espacio en tamaños pequeños no alcanza si el número es grande, te recomiendo rotarlo verticalmente, de esa manera es legible hasta cierto punto.
- Si usas la misma clase `humanX` de la imagen que vas asociar, este número automáticamente se pondrá en la misma posición.

Mira un ejemplo con tu código:

```css
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
}
.bus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
.cabeza{
  position: absolute; 
  width:4%; 
  top: 37.5%;
}

.human1 { left: 23%; }

.human2 { left: 29%; }

.human3 { left: 35%; }

.human4 { left: 67%; }

.dni{
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 background: lightgray;
 top: 30%;
 font-size: calc(0.5em + 10%);
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <img class="bus" src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX10405102.jpg" />
  <img class="cabeza human1" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
  
    <img class="cabeza human2" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
    <span class="dni human2">1516546514</span>
      <img class="cabeza human3" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
    <span class="dni human3">4578714</span>
        <img class="cabeza human4" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/11/04/666985_man_512x512.png" />
        
  
  
  
</div>
```

**¿Por qué te mencionaba lo del figure?** porque puedes aprovechar esta estructura:

```
<figure class="cabeza humanX">
  <img class="cabeza" src="cabeza-svg">
  <figcaption="dni"> 1213545646 </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Y así poder alinear perfectamente cada DNI a cada cabeza, sin tener que preocuparte por su posición con respecto a todo el bus.

Sí te quedo alguna duda, déjame tu comentario. Éxitos!

@EdgarGutierrez @G3kdigital

Comment: Me sirvio! , muchas gracias.